# Laravel Queue cant send email via Curl

Tags: php, laravel, curl, queue

I am trying to use laravel Queue

I am using the following command to send data to my queue

```
  $data = array(
        'from'=> $mailfromname .'<'.$mailfrom.'>',
        'to'=>$toname.'<'.$to.'>',
        'subject'=>$subject,
        'html'=>$html,
        'text'=>$text,
        'o:tracking'=>'yes',
        'o:tracking-clicks'=>'yes',
        'o:tracking-opens'=>'yes',
        'o:tag'=>$tag,
        'h:Reply-To'=>$replyto
    );
```

Than i send the array to my ExampleJob

```
 Queue::push(new ExampleJob($data));
```

I have than in the  in the  handle of my job a curl function that accepts the $data

So my problem here is my curl function works fine if i send the emails without using jobs  but when i use jobs I see the jobs table being populated and than it processes but no email sends using curl ... anyone know why is that  ?

```
public function handle($data)
{
     $session = curl_init(MAILGUN_URL.'/messages');
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'api:'.MAILGUN_KEY);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);
$results = json_decode($response, true);
return $results
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter for your handle method is `$data` but I only see `$array_data` being used.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the `$data` in the constructor of your job, not in the handle function

refer to this example 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#class-structure

`public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the issue , You see Curl is slow  so when using curl in ques you need to ensure that you give it adequate runtime therefore set the queue listen time out to  60 seconds .

```
php artisan queue:listen --timeout=60
```